# error analysis on nonlinear curves

Tags: standard-error, error, mse

I have a set of data from a simulation that generates a curve, and I have a mathematical model (from theory) on what things are supposed to look like. Of course, there is some error expected between theory and simulation.

I wanted to do something like R^2 from linear regression, but of course, this is only restricted to linear functions. The curve is in no way linear.

I would like to ask what other error analysis techniques are possible here.

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: What do you mean by "error analysis techniques"? What sorts of things are included or excluded from your understanding of the term? (In the case of linear models I wouldn't usually have considered $R^2$ as "error analysis".)

Comment: What I was thinking was something along the following lines:

I have a theoretical curve and a simulated curve. There is error/space in between so I was looking for the 'best' way to analyze the error in between them. How far my simulated data is from the theoretical one? I mentioned R^2 because if it were data points from a linear regression, then this would have been a very easy thing to do. But the theoretical models are in no way linear. 

Are there any other analysis possible that you can suggest? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the mean square error (MSE):
$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\hat{Y}_{i} - Y_{i})^2,$$

and the mean absolute error (MAE):
$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\hat{Y}_{i} - Y_{i}|.$$

Answer (score 0):

The most common approach is to do a $\chi^2$ fit, and use a $\chi^2$ statistic to compare the result of your fit to theory.  Briefly, this procedure is appropriate when you expect that the error between your fitted values and the values predicted by theory are Gaussian distributed.  This is what using MSE as a metric suggests.

Searching for material on $\chi^2$ fitting will yield plenty of information on what you want to accomplish.  If you want to understand this topic deeper, I'd recommend consulting a copy of [this excellent book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521150124), most of which is devoted to addressing the problem you have: how much does my data support theory?